# Cloth sim not obeying hooks

Tags: rigging, armature, physics, cloth-simulation

I have been studying techniques for creating cloth rigs recently and I hit a snag with what looks to be the commonly agreed upon solution for cloth that must move with bones, which is [hooking certain vertices of the cloth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57232/2952) to the bones of the armature.

What happens is my hooked vertices get disproportionately stretched and the rest of the mesh geometry doesn't follow realistically.

Here is a very simplified illustration of the problem (1 mesh with 3 verts hooked to bones):

[image: Hooked vertices exhibiting irrational behavior]

[image]

In this example simple edges are used, but extruding to add volume to the cloth doesn't improve it, so I don't think that's the problem. Also, I first observed this on planar cloth meshes.

Is this a problem with my settings (I've tried many configurations), or a bug, or ...what?

Thanks

Comment: In your scene mesh is binded to the rig twice, either use Armature or Hook to the bones, but not simultaneously. Cloth sim should be placed after Hooks if you want use theme

Comment: @SergeL Thanks! Good point about the order of modifiers; I completely forgot about that...unfortunately, fixing the order did not improve results. I would like to use only one (Armature or Hook mods) - but if I turn off cloth pinning the mesh falls, and for pinning I can only choose *one vertex group*, which rules out pinning to multiple bones. I chose Armature to animate in multiple directions, and Hook to give pinned verts a way to stay on. Any suggestions for how to handle this?

Comment: Just delete Hooks and it should work well

Comment: @SergeL Brilliant! Okay, that was easy. Thank you so much! I didn't realize that the pinning would be calculated after armature deformations without hooks. [Here is the fixed file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4403/) in case anyone else wants to reference the solved setup. And if you care to post an answer I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cloth pinning option works regardless of modifiers.** So there is no need in using *Hook* modifier on top of *Armature* to exclude some vertices from *Cloth* simulation.

Fixed file with deleted *Hooks* (from author's comment):

[image]